# Proving that if $n$ divides $p^{\alpha}$, where $p$ is prime and $\alpha \geq 0$, then $n = p^{\beta}$, where $0 \leq \beta \leq \alpha$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think this could be done using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but I'm not sure I want to use something that strong. How do I go about this?

Comment: You need something pretty much as strong: if a prime divides a product it divides one of the factors, so no prime other than $p$ can divide a power of $p$. What does that tell you about $n$?

Comment: If you write $p^\alpha=nk$, what does that tell you about $n$ and $k$?

Comment: The answer spoiled your hint, @GTonyJacobs... but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a prime number $p$, the only divisors of $p^{\alpha }$ are $\{1,p,p^2,...,p^{\alpha}\}$

Comment: Isn't this just a rewriting of the question?

Answer (score 2):

A key property of prime numbers is:

> If $q$ is prime and $q$ divides $ab$, then $q$ divides $a$ or $q$ divides $b$.

Therefore, by induction, if $q$ divides $p^\alpha$, then $q=p$.

Hence, $p$ is the only possible prime divisor of $n$ and so $n$ is a power of $p$.

Comment: This property is called [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)